# Linux Command line: recursively overwriting every file with a gzipped version?

Tags: linux, command-line, gzip

```
______________ myFolder
```

What can I replace with _____________ to recursively gzip every file starting at myFolder and have the gzip be overwrite the file (rename the gzip file to the original filename)?

Answer (score 4):

You could also try

```
 find myFolder -type f -exec gzip {} \; -exec mv {}.gz {} \;
```

Comment: Aha, forgot about multiple -exec calls in find, me likey

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
find myFolder -type f -exec gzip {} +
```

Comment: Be aware that this will rename your files from myFile to myFile.gz

Answer (score 1):

A simple, not very elegant bash script is to simply cd in, gzip them all in a loop, and mv them back (gzip by default removes the non-compressed file):

```
#!/bin/bash
cd myFolder
for f in `find ./ -type f`
do
    gzip $f
    mv $f.gz $f
done
```

Put that in a file called "gzip_and_rename.sh" for example, chmod -775 and run it like ./gzip_and_rename.sh (if running from within myFolder itself, remove the "cd myFolder" line from the script).

Comment: And yes I do know backticks are evil, but as I said this is just a quick hack script.

Comment: why are backticks evil, what do you replace them with ?

Comment: See http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1387/backticks-are-evil